# Multiple catch statement in java

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to understand how multiple catch statement works in java. In the documentation, they say that you are not allowed to have related types in catch statement.

Here I have a little sample that I am playing with:

```
class a extends Exception{}

class b extends RuntimeException{}

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            System.out.println(new a() instanceof Exception);
            System.out.println(new b() instanceof Exception);
            throw new a();
        }catch(a | b e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

Both classes are instance of Exception. First, one is obvious way and second inherit from RuntimeException and RuntimeExeption inherit Exception.

So why is this code compiling? Shouldn't exception **a** cover also exception **b**?
Thank you

Comment: `Shouldn't exception a cover also exception b?` What if an `b` is thrown? How would an `a` catch that?

Comment: On a side note, you should use `A`, `B` and `Test` as the class names.

Comment: I think the specification is a bit more specific: "It is a compile-time error if a union of types contains two alternatives `Di` and `Dj` (i ≠ j) where `Di` is a **subtype** of `Dj` " - so nothing about having a common ancestor (wouldn't work because all Exception must be a descendant of Throwable: "Each class type used in the denotation of the type of an exception parameter must be the class `Throwable` or a subclass of `Throwable`")

Comment: Please follow the naming conventions.  Classes (which your exceptions a and b are) should start with an uppercase character.  For exceptions also end with “Exception”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By `related types` I believe the relationship they are referring to is the extends (or subclass) relationship. So in your case you have:

```
Exception 
├── a
└── RuntimeException
    └── b
```

a is a subclass of Exception

b is a subclass of RuntimeException which is a subclass of Exception

a is not a subclass of b
AND b is not a subclass of a

Therefore the enhanced catch block can catch a and b.

Comment: Yes, Kyle. Now makes sense.